# Book about a group of heroes setting out to kill the king of demons

Tags: story-identification, books

A book I remember reading as a pre-teen.  It had to have been published in the late 70s or early 80s.  It was about a group of heroes setting out to slay a king of demons (or monsters, I can’t remember which).  The demons ruled the world and had enslaved humanity.  The book was either a sequel or the third in a trilogy since the main character recalls events from the last book.  He lived in a small village and didn’t know that demons ruled the world until a few showed up and killed everyone.  He somehow killed a demon with a magic sword by the end of that book with the help of a wizard.

One thing that stood out was that, though magic was rare, people had abilities called “talents”, like second sight or telekinesis.  Only magic, however, could actually kill a demon.  At the end the characters are all mortally wounded but a god takes pity on them after the main character asks him to help his friends.  I remember a side character was a woman named “Arrow” whose talent was being very strong.